# Linkedin authentication using AngularJS Satellizer module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, linkedin-api, satellizer

I am using Satellizer module for Social Login & Signup.
I am able to authenticate Instagram but during Linkedin authentication process, I am getting following error -

```
{ 
  error_description: 'missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : client_secret',
  error: 'invalid_request' 
}
```

I have checked numerous times but could not get this resolved.
Below is the code I am using-

```
var accessTokenUrl = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken';
var peopleApiUrl = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,headline,location,industry,summary,specialties,positions,picture-urls::(original))';

var params = {
    client_id: req.body.clientId,
    client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    code: req.body.code,
    redirect_uri: req.body.redirectUri,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
};
request.post(accessTokenUrl, {form: params, json: true }, function (err, response, body) {

    if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return res.status(response.statusCode).send({message: body.error_description});
    }
    var params = {
        oauth2_access_token: body.access_token,
        format: 'json'
    };
  // Other relevant code
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using set content type header for request `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

From [LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2)

```
POST /oauth/v2/accessToken HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.linkedin.com
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

    grant_type=authorization_code&code=987654321&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myapp.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin&client_id=123456789&client_secret=shhdonottell
```

Comment: As per request module of Nodejs 
[link](https://github.com/request/request/#forms)
Since I am using "form" in my post it should automatically add that header.

Comment: Maybe problem with `json:true`, `json - sets body to JSON representation of value and adds Content-type: application/json header. Additionally, parses the response body as JSON.`

Comment: yes, changed the configuration and it worked. Thanks for the support